# cannot open '/home/user/original/AndroidManifest.xml' for reading: No such file or directory

Tags: python, compiling, application, apk-tools

I've been trying to use evil-droid to backdoor an apk. But it showed me this error.

```
] Adding permission and Hook Smali
[ ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ ]
head: cannot open '/home/user/original/AndroidManifest.xml' for reading: No such file or directory
head: cannot open '/home/user/original/AndroidManifest.xml' for reading: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /home/user/original/AndroidManifest.xml: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/home/user/payload/smali/com/metasploit/stage/MainActivity.smali': No such file or directory
sed: can't read /home/user/payload/smali/com/metasploit/stage/.smali: No such file or directory
grep: /home/user/original/AndroidManifest.xml: No such file or directory
grep: /home/user/original/AndroidManifest.xml: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /home/user/payload/smali/com/metasploit/stage/*.smali: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /home/user/original/AndroidManifest.xml: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /home/user/original/AndroidManifest.xml: No such file or directory
grep: /home/user/original/AndroidManifest.xml: No such file or directory
grep: android.intent.category.LAUNCHER: invalid context length argument
grep: android.intent.action.MAIN: invalid context length argument
grep: android.intent.action.MAIN: invalid context length argument
grep: android.intent.category.LAUNCHER: invalid context length argument
grep: android.intent.action.MAIN: invalid context length argument
grep: android.intent.category.LAUNCHER: invalid context length argument
```

Please someone help me!! I've been searching for a solution for hours now!!

Comment: Note android is not Unix. The site title means Gnu/Linux, not any system with Linux. But the name of the site is the name of the site. So I will vote up.

Comment: Some of the tags you used for your question seem to be wrong. Maybe you should tell what APK you are trying to modify and provide a link. The script `evil-droid` uses a compiled Java program in `apktool.jar` for "Decompiling Original APK" into `$path/original`. So it may be a problem or deficiency in `apktool.jar` or a problem/feature of the APK if there is no file `AndroidManifest.xml`. Maybe you can get support by writing an issue ticket for Evil-Droid or Apktool, but the author of Apktook might not consider Evil-Droid as a good use.

Comment: You are probably passing in the wrong paths, but this is impossible to tell without knowing the exact command you ran. Edit your question to include this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue moving the apk that would be modified to the same folder where the payload apk would be created. The route is: /Evil-Droid-master/evilapk/